# UCM Clearcase: Feature stream and Recommend Baseline

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I created a feature stream yesterday.

> Mainstream(US Mastership)
>
> |
>
> |----FeatureStream(US Mastership)
>
> ```
>              |
>
>              |---FeatureStreamIndia(India Mastership)
>
>              |
>
>              |---FeatureStreamIndia(Germany Mastership)
> ```

I forgot to Recommend Baseline. I did not do it on any of the above streams.
Another, more experienced guy, told me that the structure created is useless(due to Recommend Baseline not being performed) and should be removed and new structure should be created.

What he failed to do is to properly transfer his knowledge or convince me of his logic.

What I want to know is:

> Why can I not Recommend Baseline after creating the above structure?
>
> Why do I need to create a new structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless ClearCase (multisite) comes up with an error message when you try and recommend a baseline on `MainStream` (in order to initialize automatically `FeatureStream` with the right baseline), you should be able to define one recommended baseline after creating those streams.

If it is really impossible, then deleting / recreating those stream is only possible if there is no view and no activity attached to said streams, so don't leave that situation unattended too long.

(and don't forget the CCRC alternative to multisite ;) [you can recommend baseline with a remote client](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090&aid=1))

Comment: @msiyer yes, if an error must occur, I suspect it would be when you try and recommend the baseline.